# Can't change the format of Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to make my DateTimePicker format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` because it is the format that I've inserted in my database.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repdate" name="repdate" placeholder="Report date" required>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code I wrote to change the format, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(function () {        
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Please define _but it doesn't work_. Can you put up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' use instead

Comment: Also, `$(document).ready()` and `$(function())` are the same. You're doing it wrong by nesting them. Choose and use a single one.

Comment: Your selector `$('.datepicker')` won't find any suitable element in the page.

Comment: @MelanciaUK sorry.. i am just a beginner in JS. then please provide an answer to change the format well

Comment: It's not just about the `DateTimePicker` here. Your code has other problems that won't let you even see the plugin running.

Comment: @MelanciaUK  when i was clicking the input type , the calendar shows but it's thesame i put the class <div class="input-group date datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">

Comment: It's mandatory here that you let us know which plugin you're using, because there are way too many sharing the name `DateTimePicker`. As I suggested, create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK sorry i dont knw how to jsFiddle here it is https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26132/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your jQuery selector, you should use `$('[data-provide="datepicker"]')` instead of `$('.datepicker')` or add a `datepicker` class to your input.

Here a working example:

```js
$('[data-provide="datepicker"]').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repdate" name="repdate" placeholder="Report date" required>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    scrollInput: false
  });
```

Comment: what ???? First you need to explain your answer, second it's obviously that you did a copy/paste since you are even putting unnecessary options and even the jquery selector not the same as in the question

Comment: @Ryad.iv Thank you for your concern, but please refrain from such a negative tone in your criticism. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryad.iv It is self explanatory. The code I have taken is from my personal project. The documentation can be found here http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker. I am using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.4.1. I'm sorry for not putting appropriate description as I thought the author would be familiar with jQuery.

Comment: @DecoderReloaded my two cents are thate the author is not the only reader though :) Lot's of people with different familiarity of jQUery are reading the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code, it uses a datepicker class but you are not using it correctly. You should use it like below

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group date datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repdate" name="repdate" placeholder="Report date" required>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, you do not have to use the same format in your database as you can update the date on your backend code with the proper database format later.